# Addressing someone with no specified gender

Tags: pronouns, grammatical-gender, singular-they

How do you address someone whose gender is not specified, when you are writing something? Take this as an example:

> The teacher said we should go; `____` said we are good pupils.

Would you insert *he* or *she*?

I’ve often read *she* in these cases, but is this a general rule?

Comment: The reason you often read *she* there is because grade-school teachers are often women.  For a generic, unspecified gender, just use *they*. “If someone told you you could go home early, they must think that you’re good students.”

Comment: @tchrist many people have taken to using _she_ when the gender is unknown in the same way that historically we would use _he_.

Comment: @terdon That is jolting and ungrammatical, and quite annoying. Please never do that.

Comment: @tchrist Based on previous experience with your posts I am afraid I am probably wrong but I don't see why it's ungrammatical (whether it is jolting or not is up to the reader of course). I posted this as a [question](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/108457/25030), come convince me there so we don't spam the comments section.

Comment: @terdon: Yes, this is a question where 'according to whose grammar?' should be addressed before the label 'ungrammatical' is hurled in. I also find the usage jolting, but would argue that many would say that the choice of 'they' for the clumsy 'he / she' or 's/he' is equally if not more ungrammatical.